# How do I use conio.h and dos.h with gcc?

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to learn C++ and I using YouTube, but there in code are modules `conio.h` and `dos.h`. But GCC don't knows them. Which whit the same functions I can use? (Any from another questions about this don't solving my problem)

I tried remove `conio.h` from code, but in the code, I have functions from it. That same with `dos.h`. After that, my text editor offered to me module `coco_conio.h`. What is that?

Functions , that I think that are from `conio.h` and `dos.h`:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <dos.h>
HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
COORD CursorPosition;
void setcursor(bool visible, DWORD size) {
CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO lpcursor;
lpCursor.bvisible = visible;
lpCursor.dwSize = size;
SetConsoleCursorInfo(console, &lpCursor);
getch();
if(kbhit()) {
```

Comment: *and I using YouTube* -- Well, that's your first mistake.

Comment: A poor choice of tutorial, that's all. `dos.h` sounds like something for DOS, which is an ancient OS you're not using.

Comment: are you using windows?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to compile program for Windows without Windows SDK. Also, not sure if GCC will be able to work with it (probably not). Better to use msvc or clang-cl.

Comment: I guess there are good youtube C++ tutorials, I suggest you try and find one instead of flogging this dead horse. Make sure that any tutorial covers the operating system you are using and the compiler you are using.

Comment: Even if you got this to work, I can't see anything about that code that makes it suitable for a newbie learning C++.

Comment: @user253751 No, I using Arch Linux.

Comment: @john I copied it from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4LyyvGLABg) video.

Comment: @Vioar then you don't have these because they are from Windows

Comment: Windows? Hell, they're from the stuff that *preceded* Windows.

Comment: Recommendation: Forget Youtube and the Internet for now and get an up-to-date C++ programming book. [Most of the introductory ones listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/4581301) were written in the last decade-or-so. You'll learn enough from any of them to be able to recognize Internet material that isn't hilariously wrong, ridiculously out of date, or targeting different operating systems more often than you otherwise would.

Comment: @Vioar I watched that video, From what I saw the video has no audio, it's just a screen capture of him typing some code on his computer. How did you think you would learn anything from that? I'm amazed and shocked. If you want to learn to program then find a video that at least tries to explain concepts. You will learn almost nothing from just copying. Better still buy a book.

Comment: Worse, it looks like the code is being typed automatically. OP, this is an extremely poor choice of a tutorial.

Comment: Could you show us the youtube link you are following. I 'm very curious to see how one managed to use DOS with gcc nowadays.

Comment: There are lots of muppets out there who go out of their way to get Turbo C running through MS DOS emulators, hacks, abstraction layers and so on. As if MS DOS programming in Turbo C was somehow the epitome in the history of programming. Particularly from a large country in the east with a poor school system that still uses Turbo C for teaching. Thousands of MS DOS programmers graduate from that country every year, prepared for their future careers working with single-threaded Borland BGI graphics. Or maybe as MS DOS influencers on social media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code here is a mix of the Windows API and old MS DOS libraries for the Borland Turbo compilers from 1989. You should be studying neither if your goal is to learn C++. gcc/mingw only supports Windows, not MS DOS nor 30 year old Borland-specific libraries.

General advise:

- Don't search for knowledge or wisdom on Youtube.
- Reading books or taking classes are still the best bets for obtaining relevant and correct knowledge.
- If you are new to programming then starting with C++ is a poor choice, since it's by far the most complex programming language out there. Python, Java or C# might be more suitable as first language.
- Study object-orientated design at the same time as you are learning programming.
- Learning C before C++ isn't a bad idea since C++ is largely based on C and the languages have lots of similarities.

Comment: I always started my students from C++ since if they manage it, Java and C# can be taken within a few days.